# Page reloads multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I don't have URL rewrite code in my web.config. But still my page reloads multiple times depending on number of js file references added. This issue occurs if I pass query string or parameter in URL

Ex:

http://localhost:50853/Test.aspx  -> No issue
http://localhost:50853/Test.aspx/12345  -> Page reloads multiple times

I believe this issue is due to auto url rewriting rule. Is there any way to stop auto url rewriting?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.